# One resource file per language for entire asp.net core project

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

Is it possible to just have only one resource file (per language) for the entire project in stead of per controller and per view (as mentioned in the manual https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/localization.html)?

A resource file per controller and language seems a bit overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is possible. You've to override `StringLocalizer` and `StringLocalizerFactory`. With those custom you can store resource in one or many files, in the database or in the JSON files. Or do other magic...

And then all you need to do is to register your custom service:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<IStringLocalizerFactory, YOUR_LOCALIZER_FACTORY>();
}
```

Comment: Do you have an example of this solution? I'm dealing with the same problem right now...

Comment: Would you add the example?

Answer (score -2):

The provided link, will you explain step for step with a with a detailed example. How to implement a SharedResource file, how to use it in your views or pages. When implementing this solution it still stays possible to create and use Recourse file that are strictly linked to a view or page.

Some simple steps listed in the article.

1. Create your own service class

```cs
        public class SharedLocalizerService
        {
    
            private readonly IStringLocalizer _localizer;
 
            public SharedLocalizerService(IStringLocalizerFactory factory)
            {
                var type = typeof(SharedResource);
                var assemblyName = new AssemblyName(type.GetTypeInfo().Assembly.FullName!);
                _localizer = factory.Create("SharedResource", assemblyName.Name!);
                // SharedResource as name of the resource file that will be used globally

        }
 
            public LocalizedString LocalizedHtmlString(string key)
            {
                return _localizer[key];
            }
    
       }

       public class SharedResource
       {
           // Dummy class to group shared resources
       }
```

2. In Program.cs add your service

```cs
builder.Services.AddSingleton<SharedLocalizerService>();

builder.Services.AddMvc().AddViewLocalization().AddDataAnnotationsLocalization(options =>
{
    options.DataAnnotationLocalizerProvider = (type, factory) =>
    {
        var assemblyName = new AssemblyName(typeof(SharedResource).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.FullName!);
        return factory.Create("SharedResource", assemblyName.Name!);
    };
});
```

3. Add The localization option to the builder

```cs
var locOptions = ((IApplicationBuilder)app).ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();
app.UseRequestLocalization(locOptions.Value);
```

4. Creata a resource file with som key values
5. Use it in your views

```cs
 
@inject SharedLocalizerService SharedLocalizer
 
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = @SharedLocalizer.LocalizedHtmlString("register");
}
```

https://damienbod.com/2017/11/01/shared-localization-in-asp-net-core-mvc/

Comment: bramvanpevenage, a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)